# ListView in ConstraintLayout expands to full-screen in the preview

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, listview

I am trying to include `ListView` in the `ConstraintLayout` in Android Studio. But if I am not specifying the margin, the view expands to full-screen in the design preview. And the `constraintBottom_toTopOf` parameter doesn't help for some case. Is this a bug of the IDE or is this a way the `ListView` works? Am I able to restrict `ListView` so that it ends before the top of another view despite of it's size and without specifying the large margin?

Here's the XML code:

```
    <ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/input"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

The design preview:

[image: ListView fills all the space]

Comment: You can use relative layout to do so

Comment: Can you try  android:layout_height="0dp" or "match_constraint"?

Comment: @KishanMaurya, is there an option "match_constraint" at all? IDE tells there's no such thing.

Comment: My bad... You can use 0dp here.. Which means match constrains.   0dp signifies for match constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer :

```
  <ListView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/input"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```